# How to use "nationwide"

Tags: expressions, word-order

In the following case, please advise whether "nationwide" should be put, before or after(end of the sentence), or both of them are okay?

> We reached out to universities nationwide.

or

> We reached out nationwide to universities.

Comment: I think both are acceptable, but I think the first sounds better.

Comment: please use comments to ask for clarification. Write answers as answers.

Answer (score 1):

Since, *nation-wide* or *nationwide* is an adjective, the second sentence is wrong.

The correct usage is;

> We reached out to universities nationwide.